# Angular 2 typescript function that lasts some time only

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to make a function that lasts for a few seconds.

Something like this :

```
limitTo(function() {

},4000 );
```

**How to limit time of a function ?**

Comment: What does "Limit" mean? Do a timeout after a while or run it in a loop for a while?

Comment: I want that my function would work only 4 seconds. Then I could make it false.

Comment: You might want to take a look at Observables https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/overview

Answer (score 0):

mybe something like:

```
var isFinished= false;

setTimeOut(function(){
    isFinished=true;
},500);

while (isFinished) {
    text += "The number is " + i;
    i++;
}
```